# Select last months records mysql from timestamp column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql DB that has a TIMESTAMP field titled date. How can I select all fields where the last month ?

Forexample 01-05-2014 then 31-05-2014 etc..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give example in details?

Comment: will show the last month

Comment: Forexample: BETWEEN  01-05-2014 then 31-05-2014 etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where timestamp_col=LAST_DAY(timestamp_col)
```

[Source](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-last_day-function.php)

Comment: you need the `last_day_of_month` ? just use `LAST_DAY(datecolumn)`

Comment: Forexample: 01-05-2014 then 31-05-2014

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding do you want this like...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where timestamp_col BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31';
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. Because I have TIMESTAMP field. We need only to use function

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DATETİME, FROM_UNIXTIME(`datetime`) TİMESTAMP
FROM table_name
WHERE DATETİME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ,  INTERVAL 1 DAY )) 
AND DATETİME < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( (LAST_DAY(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) )`